# Would this question about computer memory and BIOS be a good fit for Engineering SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Noticed you guys have an (as yet undefined) computer engineering tag. Does [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/366145/131624) seem like your cup of tea?

> I'm writing a little toy operating system using a mix of C and Assembly (it's not meant to be good/fast, just meant to learn from). I know that I can issue an interrupt (i think it's INT 0x15) to check the size of installed memory, which the BIOS does for you. My question is, how does it do this? There obviously needs to be a catch-all function that it performs, because it can't guarantee two systems have the same amount of memory.

When there is a bit of doubt I prefer to ask the community before migrating or referring people. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: If you give a little bit more detail then you might be able generate an answer. So example code, type of microprocessor or microcontroller. Something tell me you trying to figure out how to determine the memory size. Correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit meh, to be honest.  The OP hasn't provided any of their background knowledge in order to help narrow the answers.  I could see that being closed as "unclear" or even "too broad".

A more solid question might be "I have written X, Y, and Z of my BIOS so far.  I'm now working on ...  I'm stuck at the point of ... and I need help with understanding to approach ..."

That makes it much easier for another user to see where the OP is at and provide an answer that addresses the actual question.